# Fading innerHTML, not full element

Tags: jquery, text, fade

I need to fade the text of a `div` without fading the container for the text. [Here is my work](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/gSzvQ/9/). I need line 8 to work like line 7 does currently so I can remove the container `div` (`content`) around the text. In other words I need to animate the color change of a `div`'s text on click. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var x = false;
    $('#changeWidth').click(function() {
        if(x){}
        else{
            x = true;
            $(".content").fadeToggle(300);
            //$("#changeWidth").html().fadeToggle(300);
            var toggleWidth = $(".inner").width() == 30 ? "350px" : "30px";
            var toggleHeight = $(".inner").height() == 10 ? "48px" : "10px";
            $('.inner').animate({ width: toggleWidth, height: toggleHeight });
            setTimeout(function(){x=false;},500);
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** Looking back at this question now months later, [**this is how I'd do it**](http://jsfiddle.net/gSzvQ/16/) using CSS transitions and a toggle

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? 'I need to fade the text of a div without having a container div for the text.' -- then why did you put your text in a div??

Comment: To show you what I wanted to achieve. I need to achieve the same goal through a different means that I described. There is no need to downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gSzvQ/11/). Does this fit your needs? You can just do this:

HTML:

```
<p class="toHide">jQuery</p>
```

JS:

```
$('.toHide').click(function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'white');
});
```

If you want to use animation for colors, you have to include this plugin: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

```
$('.toHide').click(function(){
    $(this).animate{(color: 'white'), 50};
});
```

OR you can use toggleClass() with CSS transitions!! (This is the best option!!):

```
$('.toHide').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('colorWhite');
});
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I can't have any type of container around the text including `p`s, `div`s, `span`s, etc. I updated my question to include that clarification

Comment: What does your html look like then? It has to be in some tag. There is no way to do anything if there is no tag.

Comment: I gave the link in the question, but the desired format is `<div class="inner" style="display: block;">jQuery</div>`. I need the text to fadeToggle on click

Comment: Well then, that `div` is the container, and you can either set set opacity to 0, color to white, display to none, visibility to hidden, or position off the screen.

Comment: That is very close to what I want to do, but I want to have the text fade out/in, not just abruptly change. If I include `.fadeTo` as well, it affects the whole `div`, affecting the background color which I do not want. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/gSzvQ/13/

Comment: If you want to use animation for colors, you have to include this plugin: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Comment: jQuery does not come with color animation built in, so you should use css transitions, if you really want to, you can download the jQuery-color plugin from the link in my last comment.

Comment: Well that stinks. Thanks for the answer in the comments